# FMDB how can I query data from date range on Sqlite iPhone dev

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, date, fmdb

I am trying to perform a query on a table where there is a date field and I want to query over a range of values The where clause looks like the following:

```
[db executeQuery:@"select * from test where myDate BETWEEN date('now','-7 days') and date('now')"];
```

But it doesn't seem to work  :(

Answer (score 3):

If you used `DATETIME` column with table declaration, you can do this:

```
[db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM test WHERE myDate BETWEEN ? and ?", [[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-86400*7 sinceDate:[NSDate date]], [NSDate date]];
```

Note that `-86400` is seconds of a day, negative indicates "days before" like your question.

Also note that `BETWEEN` syntax includes the very second of the date you set. Use `WHERE myDate > ? and myDate < ?` if you need non-inclusive match.